# Adding data into two different mongodb Schema using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

ownerSchema.js

```
var ownerSchema = Schema({
    fname     : String,
    lname     : String,
    shopPlace : { 
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Shop'
                }
});
var Owner = mongoose.model('Owner', ownerSchema);
```

shopSchema.js

```
var shopSchema = Schema({
    shopName  : String,
    location  : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate   : Date
});
var Shop  = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

So this are my two different schema and I am trying to insert data in this two schema but don't know the exact way as I have wrote a code to add data but for the single schema

```
const Owner = require("../models/ownerSchema");

const addTask = async (req, res) => {
  let newOwmer = new Owner(req.body);
  try {
    newOwner = await newOwner.save();
    console.log("Added Successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Here i want to know how can I add data via postman I am sending data like this from postman

```
{
  "fname"     : "tom",
  "lname"     : "Jerry",
  "ShopPlace" : {
                 "shopName" : "Juice Shop",
                 "location" : "Mumbai"
                 }
}
```

as its showing me this error

```
owner validation failed: Shop: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
```

How can i send and store data inside mongodb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "fname"     : "tom",
    "lname"     : "Jerry",
    "ShopPlace" : {
        "shopName" : "Juice Shop",
        "location" : "Mumbai"
    }
}
```

As this is your data, you're sending from postman. So at first you need to separate the Shop & Owner info from this object.

```
const ownerData = req.body;             // complete request body
const shopData  = ownerData.ShopPlace;  // pluck only "shopPlace" field from the object
delete ownerData.ShopPlace;             // now, remove the "shopPlace" field from main object (this will leave only 'fname' & 'lname' fields inside the object)
```

> You code is giving error because shop's ID (i.e. *shopPlace*) is not
> created before adding it to Owner collection.

So, you have to add **Shop** first then **Owner** as owner needs shop's id.

```
const shopPlace = new Shop(shopData);   // This `shopData` is from above step
await shopPlace.save();

ownerData.shopPlace = shopPlace.id;
await Owner.create(ownerData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create your `shop` and pass the resulting `id` to the `owner` you'd like to create. Here's an example (still needs validation and error handling of course):

```
const shop = new Shop({  
  shopName: req.body.ShopPlace.shopName
  location: req.body.ShopPlace.location
});    
await shop.save();

const owner = new Owner({
            fname: req.body.fname, 
            lname: req.body.lname, 
            shopPlace: shop._id
});
await owner.save();
```

It's described in detail in the offical mongoose-docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs

Comment: I have small doubt how i will pass shop id here `newOwner = await newOwner.save();` as you can see i am writing like this `let newOwmer = new Owner(req.body);` so how will i pass shop id ? @eol

Comment: Well as you can clearly see in the example above, you cannot pass `req.body` directly, instead you create a new object where you set `fname/lname` along with `shopPlace` set to the newly created `_id`.

Answer (score 1):

write the controller like this:

```
app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
  const owner = new Owner({
    fname: req.body.fname,
    lname: req.body.lname,
  });
  await owner.save();
  const shop = new Shop({
    shopName: req.body.shopName,
    location: req.body.location,
    startDate: req.body.startDate,
    endDate: req.body.endDate,
  });
  await shop.save();
  const update = await Owner.findByIdAndUpdate(owner._id, {
    shopPlace: shop._id,
  });
  res.send(update);
});
```

and here I send the data to the controller:

```
{
  "fname": "First Name",
  "lname": "Last Name",
  "shopName"  : "Shop Name",
  "location"  : "location Name",
  "startDate" : "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
  "endDate"   : "2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"
}
```

Comment: in the Owner model, you define shopPlace type is the ObjectId that's why you have to save the shop id. otherwise shopPalace can't refer any Model

Comment: I think in this way you can solve this.
if there is any query let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: is there any complusory to write every req.body as i have wrote only two keys here fname n lname i want to reduce those line thats why i wrote `let newOwmer = new Owner(req.body);`

Comment: is there any possible way so i can pass shop id here `let newOwmer = new Owner(req.body);` ?

Comment: maybe it doesn't  possible for this controller

Comment: @Aakash you can absolutely reduce your code lines and do cleaner code. You can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Also, you Can do this another way

```
app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
  const shop = new Shop({
    shopName: req.body.shopName,
    location: req.body.location,
    startDate: req.body.startDate,
    endDate: req.body.endDate,
  });
  await shop.save();
  const owner = new Owner({
    fname: req.body.fname,
    lname: req.body.lname,
    shopPlace: shop._id,
  });
  await owner.save();
  res.send(owner);
});
```